# How to border radius BoxGeometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have a request to use Threejs to create a rectangular box. Allows entering height, width, and depth. And especially the four sides of a rectangular box can be rounded based on the given radius.
For example, edge B has a rounded radius of 40, and edge C is 20. This can be completely applied to the remaining edges A and D.

I did some research and found that `geometry.vertices` is used
But in the latest version 0.158. it is no longer used, so I don't know what to do
Example code:

```html
<script type="importmap"> {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.158.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.158.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="three_image"></div>
<script type="module"> import * as THREE from "three";
  import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
  import WebGL from "three/addons/capabilities/WebGL.js";

  let width = 200;
  let height = 100;
  let depth = 20;

  if (WebGL.isWebGLAvailable()) {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 542 / 500, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(542, 500);
    document.getElementById("three_image").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, depth, height);
    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://i.imgur.com/2AjeceZ.jpg");
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.set(depth, width, height);
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    controls.update();
    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
  } else {
    const warning = WebGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById("three_image").appendChild(warning);
  }
</script>
```

Current results:
[image]

Desired results (The red text is the caption for the image):
[image]

Thank all!

Comment: ExtrudeGeometry is an option.